# Redefined `epsilon` to `varepsilon`

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math, renewcommand, libertinus

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{libertinus}
    \renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}
    This is \texttt{varepsilon}: $\varepsilon$.

    This is \texttt{epsilon}, which should be looked the same as \texttt{varepsilon} $\epsilon$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using `XeLaTeX`. I can't redefine `epsilon` to `varepsilon`, as in the picture above. However, if I switch to `pdfLaTeX`, this does not happen.

For some reason, I have to use `XeLaTeX`. How can I modify my code to get the variant ε when I enter `epsilon`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the instruction `\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}` to *after* the `\begin{document}` directive. This is necessary because the `libertinus` package, if used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, defers some of its setup work until the end of the preamble is reached.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}  

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

varepsilon: $\varepsilon$ \quad epsilon: $\epsilon$
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly

Answer (score 7):

Since `libertinus-otf` uses `unicode-math`, you need to delay the setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}}

\begin{document}

This is \texttt{varepsilon}: $\varepsilon$.

This is \texttt{epsilon}, which should be looked the same as 
\texttt{varepsilon} $\epsilon$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is preferable because it keeps setup in the preamble.